# Strange behaviour of parseInt on event

Tags: javascript, parseint

I have a function which need to accept both a number and an event. In case of event I will extract that number from target element's attribute. Something like this...

```
function f(num) {
    if(parseInt(num) == NaN) {
        num = num.target.num
    }
    // Do something with num
}
```

The result of `parseInt(event)` is `NaN`. But strangely the result of `parseInt(event) == NaN` or `parseInt(event)===NaN` is `false`.

Can someone explain what's going on here?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>


<button onclick="f()">Click me</button>
<p>parseInt(event): <span id="a"></span></p>
<p>parseInt(event)==NaN: <span id="b"></span></p>

<script>
function f(event){
  document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = parseInt(event)
  document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = (parseInt(event)==NaN)
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: don't test for `NaN` with `==`, use `isNaN()` instead ([link to doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NaN compares unequal (via ==, !=, ===, and !==) to any other value -- including to another NaN value. Use Number.isNaN() or isNaN() to most clearly determine whether a value is NaN.

For detailed explanation, visit the following:-

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN